# What type of filter is this?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, filter

In the following SMPS circuit I was wondering  what is the type of filter at the input (marked in red). It's neither  pi or t type as far as i can tell.[image: SMPS]

Comment: Looks like a balanced EMI pi-filter to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a \$\pi\$ filter but it's a differential \$\pi\$ filter and it's also possible that both inductors are magnetically coupled. If they are then it's likely that its function is to reduce common mode currents from the switching elements getting back up the power cord i.e. it's presence is to reduce EMI.

Answer (score 5):

It's a pi filter, but for a differential signal rather than single-ended (or "unbalanced").